# How to print 'x' if the input int is b/w the desired numbers in python?

Tags: python

So, I started making a program and now I require it to print anything I like if the number is between 1-100, How to I make the program realize that it needs to print it if the number's between 90 and 100?

```
#This is a sample code
F2 = int(input())
if F2 == range(90 , 100):
    print("A")
else:
    print("BRUH")
```

I'm really new to this, I'll be very thankful if someone could help me

Comment: Don't use == but in : if F2 in range(90,100) ; and note that the upper range is EXCLUDED, so if you want integers from 90 to 100 included, use range(90,101).

Comment: `==` matches F2 exactly with range(90, 100). `in` matches F2 if it is found inside range(90, 100)

Answer (score 2):

You're checking if f2 is equal to range(90,100), correct form is if it's IN the range(90,100).

```
if F2 in range(90,101): #last number is not included in range(101 won't be included)
    print('A')
```

also, if you try

```
f2 = range(90,100)
print(f2)
```

you'll understand what f2 == range(90,100) means.

if you use in, code will check if f2 in [90,91,92...100] , if f2 will be equal any of them, then returns True.

Comment: This is correct!

Answer (score 1):

Simply do an if else check and if it falls under the range of 90 to 100 then it will print.

```
#This is a sample code
F2 = int(input())
if F2 >=90 and F2 <=100:
    print("A")
else:
    print("BRUH")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `in` operator for membership test. `==` is comparison operator for equality.

```
print("A" if (F2 := int(input())) in range(90,101) else "BRUH")
```